# Weird redis save sequence and freezing

Tags: redis, save

I face a situation where the saving sequence causes periodically, almost every hour, a redis client freeze for a couple of minutes.

Below is a redis.log extract that exhibits the weird save sequence that freezes the service. Note that all sequences below run normally except the third one

```
[5485] 15 May 12:06:43 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:06:43 * Background saving started by pid 2715
[2715] 15 May 12:06:55 * DB saved on disk
[5485] 15 May 12:06:55 * Background saving terminated with success

[5485] 15 May 12:08:44 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:08:44 * Background saving started by pid 2907
[2907] 15 May 12:08:55 * DB saved on disk
[5485] 15 May 12:08:55 * Background saving terminated with success

[5485] 15 May 12:12:59 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:12:59 * Background saving started by pid 3352
[3352] 15 May 12:13:10 * DB saved on disk
[3553] 15 May 12:14:21 * DB saved on disk
[3647] 15 May 12:15:42 * DB saved on disk
[3751] 15 May 12:16:53 * DB saved on disk

[5485] 15 May 12:17:54 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:17:54 * Background saving started by pid 3845
[3845] 15 May 12:18:04 * DB saved on disk
[5485] 15 May 12:18:05 * Background saving terminated with success

[5485] 15 May 12:19:06 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:19:06 * Background saving started by pid 4040
[4040] 15 May 12:19:16 * DB saved on disk
[5485] 15 May 12:19:16 * Background saving terminated with success
```

More precisely, if we focus on the buggy sequence here :

```
[5485] 15 May 12:12:59 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[5485] 15 May 12:12:59 * Background saving started by pid 3352
[3352] 15 May 12:13:10 * DB saved on disk
[3553] 15 May 12:14:21 * DB saved on disk
[3647] 15 May 12:15:42 * DB saved on disk
[3751] 15 May 12:16:53 * DB saved on disk
```

We see that the parent process [5485] successfully detects the need for saving, starts it with child process [3352]. The subprocess claims success after 11 seconds but the parent process does not acknowledge it. Then we can see what appears to be 3 other saving tentatives by child processes [3553], [3647] and [3751]. None of the four being acknowledged before the next save is triggered by the parent process.

What could cause that strange behavior?

Why would it freeze redis clients?

Thanks a lot for your help, we have serious actual production issues as I speak.

Comment: It seems that you have some cron job that called `SAVE` command for 3 times. And the `SAVE` command blocks Redis until it finishes saving.

Comment: Yeah, it seams, but I don't. Plus, it wouldn't explain why the first one doesn't get acknowledged by parent process.

Comment: How many Redis instances to you have on the machine? Maybe a conflict? Can you sitch Redis log to a more detailed output?

Comment: I actually have a single Redis instance on the server. It appeared that the storage failure was due to a disk IO overload. Yet I don't understand the sequence shown in the log, with multiple saving attempts by other processes than the main one.

Comment: We finally solved (dodged) the problem by removing DB saving, since we only use Redis as a volatile data cache and session booster. I'm still very interesting in any explanation though.